# Error when passing the "weights" argument to the coxph function using riskRegression in R

Tags: r, parameter-passing, cox-regression

I am trying to use inverse probability of treatment weighting in a cause-specific cox regression using the `CSC` function in the `riskRegression` Package.

I calculated the weights without a problem, but when I try to pass the weights to the `CSC` function I get the following error message:

```
Error in eval(extras, data, env) : 
  ..1 used in an incorrect context, no ... to look in
```

A complete reproducible example looks like this:

```
library(ipw)
library(cmprsk)
library(survival)
library(riskRegression)

data(mgus2)

# get some example data
mgus2$etime <- with(mgus2, ifelse(pstat==0, futime, ptime))
mgus2$event <- with(mgus2, ifelse(pstat==0, 2*death, 1))
mgus2$event <- factor(mgus2$event, 0:2, labels=c("censor", "pcm", "death"))
mgus2$age_cat <- cut(mgus2$age, breaks=seq(0, 100, 25))
mgus2$sex <- ifelse(mgus2$sex=="F", 0, 1)

# remove NA
mgus2 <- subset(mgus2, !is.na(mspike))

# estimate inverse probability weights
weights <- ipwpoint(sex, "binomial", "logit", denominator= ~ age_cat + mspike, 
                    data=mgus2)
mgus2$weights <- weights$ipw.weights

# rerun cox model using weights
mod2 <- CSC(Hist(etime, event) ~ sex + age_cat + mspike, cause="pcm",
            surv.type="hazard", fitter="coxph", data=mgus2,
            weights=weights)
```

I know from the documentation that the `CSC` function calls the `coxph` function internally, passing additional arguments to it using `...` syntax. Other arguments could be passed to the function just fine, but the `weight` argument always produces the error message above.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I have contacted the Package Maintainer and he has fixed the bug already. It should work fine now, with one little difference: Instead of `weights=weights` one has to use `weights=mgus2$weights`.